# Typescript not loading merged declaration

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, express-session

After upgrading typescript and express-session, the tsc is loading custom type defination stubs.

[image]

I am getting this error even though i have merged type declaration here

[image]

Also i have added `./typing-stubs` in tsconfig.json

```json
"typeRoots": [
      "./typing-stubs",
      "./node_modules/@types"
],
```

The problem is, type merging for `express` is loading but not for `express-session`

[image]

Comment: Did You install @types/express and @types/express-session ?

Comment: Yes. I have already installed these two packages. `@types/express@4.17.9` and `@types/express-session@1.17.1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just got the answer from the express team on the [issue](https://github.com/expressjs/session/issues/792)

The interface declared for `req.session` is changed from `SessionData` to `Session` from @types/express-session 1.17.0 → 1.17.1. You can see here https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/express-session

So the fix is

```
declare module "express-session" {
  interface Session {
    user: string;
  }
}
```